# AsyncTask que me traiga un valor de la base de datos

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sqlite

Estoy utilizando las `AsyncTask` y lo que ocupo hacer es que en cada vez que se actualice un dato de mi base de datos me aparezca en tiempo real ese dato nuevo.

Para ello ocupo esa la `AsyncTask` pero no se como programarla para que cada cierto tiempo me este consultando la bd y cuando detecte el nuevo dato me lo traiga.

```
class TemperaturaAsynctask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s){
        super.onPostExecute(s);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que lo ideal seria que cuando insertes el dato actualices el componente que deseas asi no tendrias una tarea en segundo plano que consuma memoria, pero si lo que deseas hacer una opcion seria usando un TimerTask

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Timer timer = new Timer();

TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {       
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {       
                try {
                     //Ejecuta tu AsyncTask                                            
                   AsyncTask myTask = new AsyncTask();
                    myTask.execute();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
};

timer.schedule(task, 0, 5000);
```

Con esto ejecutarias cada 5segundos.